# Karaf / Maven - Unable to resolve: missing requirement osgi.wiring.package

Tags: java, maven, gson, apache-karaf

I am unable to start a bundle in Karaf (version 3.0.1).

The bundle is built using maven and it imports [gson](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.3.1).

I included gson in maven as required:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
     <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
     <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The build goes fine. However, when deploying the bundle I receive this Warning from Karaf:

```
2015-05-27 12:45:07,371 | WARN  | 49-19-bin/deploy | fileinstall                      | 11 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.2.8 | Error while starting bundle: file:/Users/user/Documents/tools/MyBundle-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle MyBundle [121]: Unable to resolve 121.13: missing requirement [121.13] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.gson)(version>=2.3.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3974)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2037)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:955)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1263)[11:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.2.8]
at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1235)[11:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.2.8]
at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startAllBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1224)[11:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.2.8]
at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:519)[11:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.2.8]
at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:308)[11:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.2.8]
```

The bundle is not installed.

The `Import-Package` in the `MANIFEST.MF` begins with:

```
Import-Package: com.google.gson;version="[2.3,3)"
```

I tried to change it with:

```
Import-Package: com.google.code.gson;version="[2.3,3)"
```

But it gives me a similar error:

```
missing requirement [121.13] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.code.gson)
```

The `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>groupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactid</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>groupid</groupId>
<artifactId>MyBundle</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>bundle</packaging>

<name>MyBundle</name>
<description>MyBundle</description>

<properties>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.felix.http.jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.org.json</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                  <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

The `MANIFEST.MF` of Google GSON (the version maven downloads when I build the bundle) is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Export-Package: com.google.gson;version=2.3.1, com.google.gson.annotat
 ions;version=2.3.1, com.google.gson.reflect;version=2.3.1, com.google
 .gson.stream;version=2.3.1, com.google.gson.internal;version=2.3.1, c
 om.google.gson.internal.bind;version=2.3.1
Bundle-ClassPath: .
Built-By: inder
Bundle-Name: Gson
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.2.1
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.5, JavaSE-1.6, JavaSE-1.7,
  JavaSE-1.8
Bundle-Vendor: Google Gson Project
Bundle-ContactAddress: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_65
Bundle-Version: 2.3.1
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Description: Google Gson library
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.google.gson
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

I also tried with

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Import-Package>*;resolution:=optional</Import-Package>
                    <Embed-Dependency>*</Embed-Dependency>
                    <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now the dependencies are embedded but Karaf cannot start the bundle.

Comment: Are you aware of the mismatch in packages between `<groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>` and `osgi.wiring.package=com.google.gson`?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I searched for the package `com.google.gson` but afaik there is only `com.google.code.gson`. However, I do not know why the required package is `com.google.gson`.. Any clue?

Comment: Looks like it should be OK.  Can you post your bundle configuration from yout POM, `Import-Package` etc.?

Comment: Updated, I have hidden some proprietary information but it should be ok.. In case tell me.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I believe you have two options here.

If you have `Import-Package: com.google.gson;version="[2.3,3)"` in your `MANIFEST.MF`, this means that you want some package to be imported from a deployed bundle, not from an embedded jar. In this case, you should first deploy `gson-2.3.1.jar` bundle (copy this file to the deploy folder), and then deploy your bundle.

If you want to embed the gson library as a simple non-OSGi jar dependency, this also can be done, but then you have to exclude its packages from `Import-Package`:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
            <instructions>
                <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                <Import-Package>!com.google.gson,*</Import-Package>
                <Embed-Dependency>gson</Embed-Dependency>
            </instructions>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: The Embed-Dependecy solution solved a similiar problem resolving org.apache.derby.jdbc. Thanks!

Comment: I think there should be some changes of the <Import-Package> tag, I have tested it myself. <Import-Package>!com.google.gson,*</Import-Package>, otherwise com.google.gson will not be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem:

> "Unable to resolve blah-blah: missing requirement blah-blah
>   osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=blah-blah) Unresolved
>   requirements: [blah-blah] osgi.wiring.package;
>   (osgi.wiring.package=blah-blah)].

I had an activator class inside `src/main/java`. The problem was solved, when I created one more package inside Java and put my activator here. 
The result is `src/main/java/oneMorePackage/MyActivator`

The tags looks like this:

```
<Bundle-Activator>
       oneMorePackage.MyActivator
</Bundle-Activator>

<Private-Package>
      oneMorePackage
</Private-Package>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem:

> org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; ...... [caused by: Unable to resolve com.mycompany.somemodule/1.0.0.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement

And it was solved changing the **pom.xml** of problematic bundle (e.g. `com.mycompany.somemodule/pom.xml`):

```xml
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Export-Package>
                        com.mycompany.module.entity,
                        com.mycompany.somemodule.entity.v1,
                        com.mycompany.somemodule.entity.v2,
                        com.mycompany.somemodule.util
                    </Export-Package>
                    <Private-Package>
                        com.mycompany.somemodule,
                        com.mycompany.somemodule.translator
                    </Private-Package>
                    <Bundle-Name>Some Module</Bundle-Name>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.name}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                </instructions>
```

Initially, the problem was that I was exposing only a subset of these packages:

```xml
               ...
               <Export-Package>
                    com.mycompany.somemodule.entity.v2
                </Export-Package>
                <Private-Package>
                </Private-Package>
                ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this kind of error.
It means that a "dependency bundle" was not found by Karaf.

Install the dependency bundle first, and then install your bundle.

For example:

```
osgi:install mvn:com.yourCompany.corePackage.subPackage/yourDependencyBundle/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Then

```
osgi:install mvn:com.yourCompany.corePackage.subPackage/yourBundle/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```