# Cannot start bundle- missing requirement(osgi.wiring.package)

Tags: maven, osgi, apache-karaf, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I am new to Apache karaf and OSGI. I am trying to write and run a very simple bundle. But I am getting this error while starting that bundle:

> Error executing command: Error executing command on bundles: Unable to
>   resolve karaf [86](R 86.0): missing requirement [karaf [86](R 86.0)]
>   osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=bundle) Unresolved
>   requirements: [[karaf [86](R 86.0)] osgi.wiring.package;
>   (osgi.wiring.package=bundle)]

My pom is:
4.0.0

```
<groupId>com</groupId>
<artifactId>karaf</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>

<name>karaf Bundle</name>
<description>
    karaf OSGi bundle project.
</description>

<properties>
    <maven-bundle-plugin.version>2.5.4</maven-bundle-plugin.version>
    <osgi.version>6.0.0</osgi.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        <version>${osgi.version}</version>

        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-bundle-plugin.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                    <Bundle-Activator>bundle.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                    <Export-Package>
                        bundle*;version=${project.version}
                    </Export-Package>
                    <Import-Package>
                         org.osgi.framework,*
                    </Import-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My manifest.mf file is here.

```
> Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1394131053386
Bundle-Copyright: Copyright (c) OSGi Alliance (2000, 2014). All Rights R
 eserved.
Bundle-Description: OSGi Core Release 6, Interfaces and Classes for use 
 in compiling bundles.
Bundle-License: http://opensource.org/licenses/apache2.0.php; link="http
 ://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0"; description="Apache License, V
 ersion 2.0"
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: osgi.core
Bundle-SymbolicName: osgi.core
Bundle-Vendor: OSGi Alliance
Bundle-Version: 6.0.0.201403061837
Created-By: 1.6.0_45 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
DynamicImport-Package: *
Export-Package: org.osgi.dto;version="1.0",org.osgi.resource;version="1.
 0",org.osgi.resource.dto;version="1.0";uses:="org.osgi.dto",org.osgi.fr
 amework;version="1.8",org.osgi.framework.dto;version="1.8";uses:="org.o
 sgi.dto",org.osgi.framework.hooks.bundle;version="1.1";uses:="org.osgi.
 framework",org.osgi.framework.hooks.resolver;version="1.0";uses:="org.o
 sgi.framework.wiring",org.osgi.framework.hooks.service;version="1.1";us
 es:="org.osgi.framework",org.osgi.framework.hooks.weaving;version="1.1"
 ;uses:="org.osgi.framework.wiring",org.osgi.framework.launch;version="1
 .2";uses:="org.osgi.framework",org.osgi.framework.namespace;version="1.
 1";uses:="org.osgi.resource",org.osgi.framework.startlevel;version="1.0
 ";uses:="org.osgi.framework",org.osgi.framework.startlevel.dto;version=
 "1.0";uses:="org.osgi.dto",org.osgi.framework.wiring;version="1.2";uses
 :="org.osgi.framework,org.osgi.resource",org.osgi.framework.wiring.dto;
 version="1.2";uses:="org.osgi.dto,org.osgi.resource.dto",org.osgi.servi
 ce.condpermadmin;version="1.1.1";uses:="org.osgi.framework,org.osgi.ser
 vice.permissionadmin",org.osgi.service.packageadmin;version="1.2";uses:
 ="org.osgi.framework",org.osgi.service.permissionadmin;version="1.2",or
 g.osgi.service.startlevel;version="1.1";uses:="org.osgi.framework",org.
 osgi.service.url;version="1.0",org.osgi.util.tracker;version="1.5.1";us
 es:="org.osgi.framework"
Import-Package: javax.security.auth.x500;resolution:=optional
Tool: Bnd-2.2.0.20130927-173453
```

Comment: Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480508/karaf-maven-unable-to-resolve-missing-requirement-osgi-wiring-package) help?

Answer (score 14):

Let's break this down: "Missing requirement" simply means that your bundle has been installed into the OSGi Framework but it has a requirement that could not be satisfied by any of the other bundles that are installed.

The unresolved requirement is in the namespace `osgi.wiring.package`, which means that the kind of requirement is a Java package import, i.e. what you see as an `Import-Package` in your bundle's manifest. In other words, your bundle imports a package and no other bundle exports that package.

Finally the bit at the end, `(osgi.wiring.package=bundle)`, is a **filter** which expresses the exact package name that your bundle requires. In this case your bundle apparently imports a package named "bundle".

That is a little odd, and implies that you have probably made a mistake in the way your bundle is built. It would help if you post the details about how you built this bundle.

Comment: Hi neil, I have added my pom.xml details. But in my org.osgi jar file , I have the osgi.framework.wiring package. So, any idea why it is giving an error that its missing?

Comment: You have posted the manifest of osgi.core-6.0.0.jar, not your own bundle. Also why are you exporting a package named "bundle"?? Do you have a package called "bundle" in your Java source code? This is all very difficult to understand, I think you need to step back and tell us what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: @pres Downvoting your question because you seem to have [lost interest in solving it](http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.  After I fixed my POM I did a Maven "clean" and then a Maven "package" to ensure plugins weren't adding the entry into my manifest file.

Comment: Check the build in the pom.  The problem I had was that the entry for the Bundle-Activator was wrong and the Export-Package was wrong.

Comment: OMG, thank you! Had a typo in my imports. `(osgi.wiring.package=version)` I removed the `=0.0.0` part from `javax.annotation;version=0.0.0,` and replaced the `;` with a `,` for no reason. So whats left was: `javax.annotation,version,` which are syntax wise two correct imports. Simply `version` doesn't exist.