# "org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve" with Maven's dependency

Tags: java, maven, osgi, osgi-bundle

I am new to AEM/Maven, and was following [this simple tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lO_bJTjCdhM) to add the `json-simple` dependency.

Here is what I added to my pom.xml, and clicked on `sync` on top right to download that package.

[image]

you can see the full [pom.xml here](https://github.com/SeanLuo-FSWD/mavenrampup/blob/main/core/pom.xml).

But when I install with `mvn clean install -PautoInstallBundle`, the build is success, but in my logs I get the following error message:

```
27.07.2022 20:00:15.531 *ERROR* [Background Update rampup.core (619)] org.apache.felix.http.jetty Cannot install or update bundle from /var/folders/hh/yvvgql191_l3vb9km9bxgpm80000gp/T/install2076326317699076133.tmp (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve rampup.core [619](R 619.34): missing requirement [rampup.core [619](R 619.34)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.json.simple)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[rampup.core [619](R 619.34)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.json.simple)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))])

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve rampup.core [619](R 619.34): missing requirement [rampup.core [619](R 619.34)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.json.simple)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[rampup.core [619](R 619.34)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.json.simple)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2281)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998)
    at org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.core.BaseUpdateInstallHelper.run(BaseUpdateInstallHelper.java:198) [org.apache.felix.webconsole:4.6.2]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47508152/cannot-start-bundle-missing-requirementosgi-wiring-package) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55862916/org-osgi-framework-bundleexception-unable-to-resolve-missing-requirement-osgi). They talk about installing an export bundle, or to install the missing `org.json.simple`, but their solution are too high level for me.

Thanks for any clarification to fix this.