# How to get the karaf rest example to work?

Tags: java, rest, apache-karaf

I am stuck in getting the apache karaf rest example to work.

I successfully managed to install karaf on my laptop and get a [hello world example application](https://michaelrice.com/2015/04/the-simplest-osgi-karaf-hello-world-demo-i-could-come-up-with/) on the console to run. I also managed to compile the example applications in the C:\karaf\examples using mvn install.

As a next step I tried to "install" the rest-example as discussed in the README.md by executing the command

```
feature:repo-add mvn:org.apache.karaf.examples/karaf-rest-example-features/4.2.1-SNAPSHOT/xml
```

This resulted in the following error message:

> karaf@root()> feature:repo-add
>   mvn:org.apache.karaf.examples/karaf-rest-example-features/4.2.1-SNAPSHOT/xml
>
> Adding feature url
>   mvn:org.apache.karaf.examples/karaf-rest-example-features/4.2.1-SNAPSHOT/xml
>
> Error executing command: Error resolving artifact
>   org.apache.karaf.examples:karaf-rest-example-features:xml:4.2.1-SNAPSHOT:
>   [Could not find artifact
>   org.apache.karaf.examples:karaf-rest-example-features:xml:4.2.1-SNAPSHOT
>   in apache
>   (http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/), Could
>   not find artifact
>   org.apache.karaf.examples:karaf-rest-example-features:xml:4.2.1-SNAPSHOT
>   in ops4j.sonatype.snapshots.deploy
>   (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ops4j-snapshots/)] :
>   mvn:org.apache.karaf.examples/karaf-rest-example-features/4.2.1-SNAPSHOT/xml

See here for a screen shot of the error message
[image: Screen Shot]

**Question**: how can I get a simple rest service to start in apache karaf?

(does not have to be the example exactly, I would be happy to have some hello world example which is accessible via http.)

Thank you very much for your support!

**Update1**: I tried to install the bundles by directly adding them to my deploy directory. I am getting the following errors when trying to start up the bundles. What exactly am i missing here?

[image]

**Update2**: I have installed all the missing requirements but i still get the following error. I am very sorry for these tedious questions, but why is the org.osgi.service.blueprint requirement still missing even though the bundle is clearly installed and running (id 177)?

[image]

Comment: you should build the bundle of your rest app and then just install in karaf container by adding this bundle to deploy directory. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to see some info why a bundle isn't active you can use `bundle:diag` command.
As can be seen from screenshot your bundle has missing requirement `com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json`.

You can add missing libraries to `<Import-Package>` section of your `maven-bundle-plugin` or install these to apache karaf. This command will install dependency directly from maven repo:

```
install -s mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/2.9.7
```

Also you can download a bundle file from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/2.9.7) and install it manually by putting jar to deploy dir

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30532447/5108737) link for more info

Comment: Ok, i can use the bundle:diag command and i can see that the com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json requirement is missing. My problem is that i do not understand how to install or include the missing requirement. I read the link you posted for the details but i still have no idea how to import whats missing.

Comment: @Felix Try to download bundle file from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/2.9.7) and put it to deploy directory. Btw there is a command to install bundles directly from maven like `install -s mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/2.9.7`