# new JSONObject triggers java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, json, jdeveloper

I'm developing a custom authentication plugin for **OAM(Oracle Access Manager)** in Java language using **JDeveloper IDE**.

---

i'm parsing a `URL` and i get the variables i want from a `JSONObject` **correctly** on a `Main.class` file **without** **triggering** any kind of `Exception`

This leads me to the **assumption** that the whole **parsing code is** **correct** which means the `readJsonFromUrl` **function** does it job.

---

Let me mention what my `PhillPlugin.class` includes

1. `public ExecutionStatus process(AuthenticationContext context)` ,
   triggered when the Plug-In is to run.
2. `public void getDataGenerate(String Url)`, called inside **process** function to created the `JSONObject` from `URL`
3. `public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url)` called inside **getDataGenerate** function
4. `private static String readAll(Reader rd)` used for parsing inside **readJsonFromUrl**

---

**Now i upload the Plug-In to the server, i run it and get the following in it's Logs**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject
    at phillplugin.PhillPlugin.readJsonFromUrl(PhillPlugin.java:184)
    at phillplugin.PhillPlugin.getDataGenerate(PhillPlugin.java:132)
    at phillplugin.PhillPlugin.process(PhillPlugin.java:63)
```

---

What is needed in order to create the Plug-In:

- `PhillPlugin.class`
- `PhillPlugin.xml`
- `MANIFEST.MF`

---

I'm mentioning the above because i have to include somewhere in these files the `org.json` path. ( **it already exists as an import in** `PhillPlugin.class` and `Main.class` )

> The **org.json.jar** is included in  Project's Libraries as well as all the **.jars** in order to build the Plug-In

---

> **MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-Version: 10
Bundle-Name: PhillPlugin
Bundle-Activator: phillplugin.PhillPlugin
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0",oracle.security.am.plugin,oracle.security.am.plugin.authn,oracle.security.am.plugin.impl,oracle.security.am.plugin.api,oracle.security.am.common.utilities.principal,oracle.security.idm,javax.security.auth
Bundle-SymbolicName: PhillPlugin
CLASSPATH: felix.jar, identitystore.jar, oam-plugin.jar, utilities.jar, org.json.jar
```

> **Sample of the PhillPlugin.Class**

I'm not supposed to include the URL for security purposes. (Trust me it's Valid)

```java
    public void getDataGenerate(String Url) {
        System.out.println("-----   Reading Json Object  -----");
                       JSONObject json;
        try {
            json = readJsonFromUrl(Url);
            System.out.println("The Json Object: "+json.toString());
            otp=Integer.parseInt((String) json.get("otp"));
            System.out.println("The User is:"+user+"\n"+"His OTP is: "+otp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception : "+e.toString());
        }          

    public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException,JSONException {
        System.out.println("Opening Stream");
        InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
        System.out.println("Stream opened");
        try {
         System.out.println("----------\n\n\nUrl to Parse: "+url+"\n\n\n");
          BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
          System.out.println("\n\n\n"+"BufferedReader opened\n\n\n\n");
          String jsonText =(String) readAll(rd);
          System.out.println("\n\n\nJsonTEXT:"+jsonText+"\n\n\n");
            JSONObject json=null;
            System.out.println("\n\n Created Json Instance\n\n\n");
            try{
                System.out.println("inside try statement - initializing JSONObject with the text above \n\n\n");
             //-------ERROR TRIGGERED HERE---------
             json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
                System.out.println("--------------------Object created-------------------");
            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\nJSONOBJECT failed to be created: \n"+e);
            }
          System.out.println("\n\n\nJSON OBJECT"+json+"\n\n\n\n");
          return json;
        } finally {
          is.close();
        }

    private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int cp;
        while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
          sb.append((char) cp);
        }
        return sb.toString();
      }
```

> **PhillPlugin.xml**

```xml
<Plugin type="Authentication">
    <author>uid=Phill</author>
    <email>phill@oracle.com</email>
    <creationDate>12:47:00, 2019-07-11</creationDate>
    <description>Phill-Plugin Prints Hello</description>
    <configuration>
    </configuration>
</Plugin>
```

---

This is the **output** on server Logs **before crashing**:

```
Stream opened
----------
Url to Parse: https://something

BufferedReader opened

JsonTEXT: it's correct

Created Json Instance

inside try statement - initializing JSONObject with the text above
```

> I'm worrying too much about the `MANIFEST.MF` file because probably i'm
>   doing something wrong in there

Sorry for the long post, i will provide any extra information if needed, Thank you

Comment: in manifest: it's "Class-Path:" not CLASSPATH but it should be generated using maven for example, since there are other restrictions (line size, spaces on carriage return ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing an `Authenticaiton Plugin` for `OAM` Server , all extra libraries should be mentioned in `MANIFEST.MF` as well as the external `.jar` files.

Furthermore , all `.jar` files should be deployed in the final plugin `.jar` as well as the external `libraries`

In my case i had to include `org.json.jar` at the exported `PhillPlugin.jar` as follows:

- **PhillPlugin.jar**

[image]

as you can see both `org.json.jar` and it's libraries `org` are required

- **Manifest.MF**

The last step is to mention in `MANIFEST.MF` all the extra `classes` that you are using in your plugin

In my case i had to include this in my `Import-Package` Attribute in order to be able to create a `JSONObject` instance

```
org.json;resolution:=optional,
org.json.JSONObject;resolution:=optional
```

If you would like to use a `JSONArray` you had to add this:

```
org.json.JSONArray;resolution:=optional
```

and so on.

**Edit:** The class-path should be mentioned as follows:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: org.json.jar, felix.jar, identity-provider.jar, oam-plugin.jar, utilities.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CLASSPATH` entry in the `MANIFEST.MF` is obviously wrong. Correct name is `Class-Path` see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Whole MANIFEST.MF documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html

Comment: it might be, but `CLASSPATH`  worked for me, if it was wrong i couldn't use anything from the other 4 .jars , surprisingly i can use the content of the 4 .jars except the org.json.jar

Comment: Can you please provide the imports along with your Java class excerpt because maybe what you're using might not be the same `JSONObject`. By the way, how do you obtain the `org.json.jar`?

Comment: @PhillAlexakis It is the line limit of 72 char then. Do you use any building tool for generation? Or elese you wil have to manage it manually: \n\b every 72 chars.

Comment: what exactly do you mean? i'm building the PhillPlugin.jar with  Jdeveloper, not manually with commands

Comment: @maxxyme i corrected the `Class-Path` but the error is still present

Comment: @maxxyme i'm importing the `org.json.jar`  from Jdeveloper's IDE Libraries these are my java imports `import org.json.JSONObject;`
`import org.json.JSONException;` and i'm trying to include these two imports on `Import-Package` at `MANIFEST.MF` like this `Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0",oracle.security.am.plugin,oracle.security.am.plugin.authn,oracle.security.am.plugin.impl,oracle.security.am.plugin.api,oracle.security.am.common.utilities.principal,oracle.security.idm,javax.security.auth,org.json.JSONObject,org.json.JSONException` but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: ah! the keyword is `Import-Package` thus you should only lists packages there! Neither `org.json.JSONObject` nor `org.json.JSONException` are packages actually, it's fully qualified class names (i.e. package + Class name). You should resort to just put `org.json` instead here.

Comment: yes indeed you are right, but I'm still getting a new exception on the `manifest` file exactly on the line i added `org.json`
---->     `Caused By: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle PhillPlugin [2]: Unable to resolve 2.0: missing requirement [2.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.json)`

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not an expert - even no XP at all - in OSGi, but given questions & answers here on SO it seems like you are trying to reference an extra "bundle" or "lib" in your plugin, while it can't be done that way.
Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30532447/666414 you should read it like Karaf = OAM and bundle = plugin, but the main problem seems in the maven file with generation of the MANIFEST.MF

Comment: i'll give it a try but seems the logic is the same but the illustration is different . i'll give it a shot